Error: computed is not a function when using Angular 18 in Remote and Angular 15 in Host with Module Federation
I am working on a micro-frontend architecture using Angular and Webpack Module Federation. I have a host application using Angular 15 and a remote application using Angular 18. Both applications are configured for Module Federation with the following setups:
Remote Application Configuration:
Angular Version: 18
webpack.config.js:
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(path.join(__dirname, "tsconfig.json"), []);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "remoteDashboard",
    publicPath: "auto",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },
      name: "remoteDashboard",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./HomeModule": "./src/app/components/home/home.module.ts",
        "./SettingsComponent": "./src/app/components/dashboard/settings/settings.component.ts",
      },
      shared: {
        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors(),
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: "^18.2.0" },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: "^18.2.0" },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: "^18.2.0" },
        "@angular/material": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: "^18.0.0" },
        "chart.js": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: "^4.4.0" },
        "ng2-charts": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: "^6.0.0" },
      },
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
  ],
};

Host Application Configuration:
Angular Version: 15
webpack.config.js:
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "EjarhostApp",
    publicPath: "auto",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "EjarhostApp",
      library: { type: "module" },
      shared: {
        "@angular/core": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: false,
          requiredVersion: "^15.2.9",
        },
        "@angular/common": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: false,
          requiredVersion: "^15.2.9",
        },
        "@angular/router": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: false,
          requiredVersion: "^15.2.9",
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: false,
          requiredVersion: "^15.2.9",
        },
        "@angular/material": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: false,
          requiredVersion: "^15.2.9",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

Issue:
When running the host application and accessing the remote module, I encounter the following error in the browser console:

core.mjs:8400 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: (0 ,
angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_.computed) is not a function TypeError: (0 , angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_.computed)
is not a function

Analysis:
Angular 18 introduced features like computed in @angular/core, which is not available in Angular 15.
The host application, running Angular 15, cannot interpret or execute certain features from the remote app that rely on Angular 18 functionality.
Questions:
Is it possible to use different Angular versions (15 for host and 18 for remote) in a Module Federation setup?
How can I resolve this compatibility issue, ensuring the host application does not break while consuming the remote application?
Should I align both Angular versions to avoid such issues, and if so, what are the recommended approaches?

You can have different versions but the host needs to have the highest.

@MatthieuRiegler I understand the reasoning behind this due to shared dependencies in Module Federation,but I’m wondering:
Is it possible to configure the remote app to work as a completely standalone application, relying only on itself, while still exposing modules for the host? Essentially, the remote should:
1.Be able to bootstrap and run independently (without depending on the host’s Angular version).2.Still appear in the host app through Module Federation
What would be the best approach to achieve this? Would decoupling shared dependencies completely work, or is there another solution?
